# emacs save-excursion not restoring point?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm running this function (interactive and in a hook) to reformat source code

```
(defun a-style ()                                                                                                                                                                                         
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                                           
  (save-excursion                                                                                                                                                                                         
    (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "/usr/local/bin/astyle -A10 -s4 -m0 -M40 -k1 -W0 -z2 -xd -CSKNLwYfpHjJcn" t t)))
```

but the save-excursion does not seem to work, the point always jumps to 1 (the shell command works though!). Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks,
Mario

EDIT:

So I finally did it the naive way:

```
(defun a-style ()                                                                                                                                                                                         
  (interactive)                                                                                                                                                                                           
  (setq temp-point (point))                                                                                                                                                                               
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "/usr/local/bin/astyle -A10 -s4 -m0 -M40 -k1 -W0 -z2 -xd -CSKNLwYfpHjJcn" t t)                                                                         
  (goto-char temp-point))
```

Kinda stupid, but does what I want. If anyone knows of a better solution, I'd be grateful.

Comment: How about a `let` form instead of `setq`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for `shell-command-on-region` says in part:

> If REPLACE, the optional fifth argument, is non-nil, that means insert
>   the output in place of text from START to END, putting point and mark
>   around it.

Since you have REPLACE set to `t`, it replaces all the text and puts point and mark around it, and so point goes to point-min.  Furthermore, I think when the spot previously saved by `save-excursion` is removed Emacs backs up to the beginning of the removed region which again is point-min.

I think your solution is fine.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I came across this same issue. Here is a simple macro which restores point and buffer:

```
(defmacro my-save-excursion (&rest forms)
  (let ((old-point (gensym "old-point"))
        (old-buff (gensym "old-buff")))
    `(let ((,old-point (point))
           (,old-buff (current-buffer)))
       (prog1
           (progn ,@forms)
         (unless (eq (current-buffer) ,old-buff)
           (switch-to-buffer ,old-buff))
         (goto-char ,old-point)))))
```